# How can I make my windows 10 wallpaper a jpeg from a online webcam that updates once per minute?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, desktop-customization

I would like to set my wallpaper to [this](https://wildcenter.org/summitcam/wfsummit.jpg) image and others that update regularly. Is there a way to do this with Windows 10?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can probably do this with a script, however please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).